# Github Actions: how to require more than 1 approval

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow

On github actions you can use Environments to set required approvers.
You can list multiple teams / people that can approve the job but only 1 person needs to approve it from that list.

Is there a way to require 2 people to approve a job?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible to add more than 1 approval natively for each job. But a workaround could be to set 2 jobs in sequence with the same approval list. The only issue here is that the same user could eventually approve both of them, but it may be aligned with the team before.

Comment: You could also use [this manual-approval action](https://trstringer.com/github-actions-manual-approval/) where you can inform more than 1 approver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#required-reviewers), it isn't possible (yet?) to add more than 1 approval natively for each job in an environment:

> Use required reviewers to require a specific person or team to approve workflow jobs that reference the environment. You can list up to six users or teams as reviewers. The reviewers must have at least read access to the repository. **Only one of the required reviewers needs to approve the job for it to proceed.**

A workaround could be to set 2 jobs in sequence with the same approval list. However in that case the issue may be that the same user could eventually approve both of them, but it may also be aligned with the team before.

Another option could be to use this [manual-approval action](https://trstringer.com/github-actions-manual-approval/) where you can inform more than 1 approver.